# F# function calling syntax confusion

Tags: f#

I have a piece of code:

```
links
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.GetAttributeValue ("href", "no url"))
```

Which I wanted to rewrite to:

```
links
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x.GetAttributeValue "href" "no url"))
```

But the F# compiler doesn't seem to like that.  I was under the impression that these two function calls were interchangeable:

```
f (a, b)
(f a b)
```

The error that I get is:

> The member or object constructor 'GetAttributeValue' taking 2 arguments are not accessible from this code location. All accessible versions of method 'GetAttributeValue' take 2 arguments.

Which seems amusing, as it seems to indicate that it needs what I'm giving it.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A usual function call in F# is written without parentheses and parameters are separated by spaces. The simple way to define a function of several parameters is to write this:

```
let add a b = a + b
```

As Pascal noted, this way of specifying parameters is called currying - the idea is that a function takes just a single parameter and the result is a function that takes the second parameter and returns the actual result (or another function). When calling a simple function like this one, you would write `add 10 5` and the compiler (in principle) interprets this as `((add 10) 5)`. This has some nice advantages - for example it allows you to use *partial function application* where you specify only a first few arguments of a function:

```
let addTen = add 10 // declares function that adds 10 to any argument
addTen 5  // returns 15
addTen 9  // returns 19
```

This feature is practically useful for example when processing lists:

```
// The code using explicit lambda functions..
[ 1 .. 10 ] |> List.map (fun x -> add 10 x) 

// Can be rewritten using partial function application:
[ 1 .. 10 ] |> List.map (add 10)
```

Now, let's get to the confusing part - in F#, you can also work with tuples, which are simple data types that allow you to group multiple values into a single values (note that tuples aren't related to functions in any way). You can for example write:

```
let tup = (10, "ten")    // creating a tuple
let (n, s) = tup         // extracting elements of a tuple using pattern 
printfn "n=%d s=%s" n s  // prints "n=10 s=ten"
```

When you write a function that takes parameters in parentheses separated by a comma, you're actually writing a function that takes a single parameter which is a tuple:

```
// The following function:
let add (a, b) = a * b

// ...means exactly the same thing as:
let add tup = 
  let (a, b) = tup  // extract elements of a tuple
  a * b

// You can call the function by creating tuple inline:
add (10, 5)
// .. or by creating tuple in advance
let t = (10, 5)
add t
```

This is a function of a different type - it takes a single parameter which is a tuple, while the first version was a function that took two parameters (using currying).

In F#, the situation is a bit more complicated than that - .NET methods appear as methods that take a tuple as a parameter (so you can call them with the parenthesized notation), but they are somewhat limited (e.g. you cannot create a tuple first and then call the method giving it just the tuple). Also, the compiled F# code doesn't actually produce methods in the curried form (so you cannot use partial function application directly from C#). This is due to performance reasons - most of the times, you specify all arguments and this can be implemented more efficiently.

However, the principle is that a function either takes multiple parameters or takes a tuple as a parameter.

Comment: Great answer, but note that your second-to-last paragraph is not quite correct - it's perfectly possible to pass a non-syntactic tuple to a .NET method (e.g. `let t = 1,2 in Object.ReferenceEquals t`).  This does not work for overloaded methods, however.

Comment: @kvb: Good point - I knew there were some limitations, but I wasn't exactly sure. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Awesome!  Answers like this is what make StackOverflow such a valuable place.  Thanks Thomas.

Comment: The money quote: "When you write a function that takes parameters in parentheses separated by a comma, you're actually writing a function that takes a single parameter which is a tuple." Always wondered about this, finally had the epiphany today. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: This is a great answer, but it illuminates what seems like a bad language syntax design decision. Having to different syntaxes for BCL calls and F# calls makes F# feel like a second-class citizen. It's also difficult to understand for F# beginners (like me), who have been diligently following along with the F# syntax only to be throwing this bit of wonkiness.

Answer (score 3):

In `f (a,b)`, `f` must be a function that takes a single argument (which is a pair).

In `f a b`, which is short for `(f a) b`, `f` when applied to `a` returns a function that is applied to `b`.

Both are almost equivalent ways to pass arguments to a function, but you cannot use a function designed for one style with the other. The second style is called "[currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)". It has the advantage of allowing some computations to be made as soon as `a` is passed, especially if you are going to use the same `a` with different `b`s. In this case you can write:

```
let f_a = f a (* computations happen now that a is available *)
in
f_a b1 .... f_a b2 ....
```

Comment: So (f a b) won't work for any of the other .Net lang functions, since I don't believe any of them are created to be curried?

Comment: @Daniel: I would suspect that if you define a function `f a b` in F#, you'd be able to call it as `f(a)(b)` in e.g. C# (as that is exactly what `f a b` means as Pascal pointed out).

Comment: @sepp2k: I meant to say, all calls to functions originally created in C#, VB, and maybe some of the other .net langs are of the form f(a,b), since those other languages don't support currying.

Comment: @Daniel I had never thought about this aspect of F#-.NET interoperability, but I guess you are right: you must use the first form if you intend for your F# function to be called from another language.

Comment: @Daniel: Well technically you can very well define functions that return functions in other .net languages (like `int f(int a) {return (b => a+b);}` in C#) and then use it as `f a b` in F#, but yes, since there isn't a more convenient syntax for that in other languages, it normally isn't done.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your implicit question, in this kind of situation, it can be useful to write a little helper function:

```
let getAttrVal (x:TypeOfX) key default = x.GetAttributeValue(key, default)

//usage
links |> Seq.map (fun x -> getAttrVal x "href", "no url"))
```

and depending on how you want to use it, it might be more useful to curry it 'backwards':

```
let getAttrVal key default (x:TypeOfX) = x.GetAttributeValue(key, default)

//partial application
let getHRef = getAttrVal "href" "no url"

//usage
links |> Seq.map (fun x -> getHRef x)

//or, same thing:
links |> Seq.map getHRef
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple explanation; there are two function calls in F#: curried and tupled.

```
open System 

// curried
let add x y = x + y 
add 5 <| 10 |> Console.WriteLine
(add 5) 10 |> Console.WriteLine
(add 5) <| 10 |> Console.WriteLine
add <| 5 <| 10 |> Console.WriteLine
add 5 10 |> Console.WriteLine
5 |> add <| 10 |> Console.WriteLine
Console.WriteLine(add 10 5)
Console.WriteLine((add 10) 5)
Console.WriteLine((add 10) <| 5)
Console.WriteLine((add <| 10 <| 5))

// tupled
let add'(x, y) = x + y

add'(10, 5) |> Console.WriteLine
add' <| (10, 5) |> Console.WriteLine
(10, 5) |> add' |> Console.WriteLine
Console.WriteLine(add'(10, 5))
Console.WriteLine(((10, 5) |> add'))
Console.WriteLine((add' <| (10, 5)))
```

In a curried form, we can pass values one by one; in tupled form, we pass only tuples -- pairs of values.

Comment: Your explanation can give the impression that the language itself enforces a choice between either curried syntax or tupled syntax when declaring a function, when in reality there is _only one syntax_. The other answers explain the actual situation, and gives the details necessary to understand the difference between these _two most common styles_ of specifying parameters.