# F# Operator/Function Confusion

Tags: function, f#, operator-overloading

I'm just getting started on F#, and when playing around with operator overloading, I've run into something I don't quite understand. Now, I understand that you can't use, for example, `+*` as an overloaded prefix operator; it can only be an infix operator. Here's where I get confused, however:

```
let (+*) a = a + a * a;;
```

If I run this, fsi tells me that the function `(+*)` is an `int->int`. Great, I can dig that -- it's not an overloaded operator, just a normal function named `(+*)`. So, if I do:

```
printf "%d" ((+*) 6)
```

I'll get 42, as I expect to. However, if I try:

```
printf "%d" (+*) 6
or
printf "%d" (+*)6
```

It won't compile. I can't put the exact error up right now as I don't have access to an F# compiler at this moment, but why is this? What's going on with the binding here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's interpreting this:

```
printf "%d" (+*) 6
```

Like this:

```
printf ("%d") (+*) (6)
```

In other words, passing three curried arguments to `printf`, the second of which is a reference to the function `+*`.

Comment: Ah, that makes some sense. However, the spacing syntax for parameters seems like it might make binding confusing. In what order to spaces bind parameters? I'm used to C-like languages with forced parentheses for parameters, so that kind of binding is obvious to me.

Comment: Perrako, that is a great follow-up question. Post it as a separate question so we'll have a reference for the future (ie "How to get used to F# parameter passing syntax when I am used to C-like parameters?"). (I'm sorry that I can't answer myself; I learned Lisp before F# so I got used to the space syntax that way.)

Comment: Never mind, I found this existing question which will probably answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725202/f-function-calling-syntax-confusion

Comment: Thanks for the link! It does answer the question, but not super directly. With `printf "%d" (+*) 6`, it goes left to right, calling something like: `6|>printf "%d"`. That makes sense. What I'm not so sure about is the version with the space omitted; that is to say, `printf "%d" (+*)6` How/why can the compiler insert a space there, thus making them separate parameters?

Comment: The ")" and "6" are separate lexical tokens in an expression, so it works the same way that "1+3*4" is equivalent to "1 + 3 * 4".

BTW, you can use backwards pipe to control the precedence, so 
printf "%d" <| (+*) 6
will work.