# F# Binary Arithmetic program.. type error

Tags: f#

I'm programming binary arithmetic program using F#. I don't think my code was wrong but type error occurred.

Please examine my code and tell me what is wrong.

```
let carry a b c = if a then b||c else b&&c
let sum a b c = (if c then (a=b) else not (a=b))
let rec addc cin (l1:bool list) (l2:bool list) =
    if l2.Length>0 then sum(cin,l1.Head,l2.Head)::addc(carry cin,l1.Head,l2.Head), l1.Tail, l2.Tail) else l1
```

The error message:

> if l2.Length>0 then
>   sum(cin,l1.Head,l2.Head)::addc(carry(cin,l1.Head,l2.Head),l1.Tail,l2.Tail)
>   else l1
>   --------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> stdin(173,51): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>       ('a * bool * bool -> bool -> bool) list     but here has type
>       bool list -> bool list -> ('a * bool * bool -> bool -> bool) list

Answer (score 3):

Your brackets and thus your syntax is incorrect and so the meaning of the parameters and the functions is not as intended (for example when calling the `sum` function you are calling it with one tuple parameter and not with three parameters). Adjusting the brackets corrects the problem and then the code compiles as expected:

```
let carry a b c = if a then b||c else b&&c
let sum a b c = (if c then (a=b) else not (a=b))
let rec addc cin (l1:bool list) (l2:bool list) = 
    if l2.Length > 0 then
        (sum cin l1.Head l2.Head) :: (addc (carry cin l1.Head l2.Head) l1.Tail l2.Tail)
    else
        l1
```

> val addc : cin:bool -> l1:bool list -> l2:bool list -> bool list

And a call to `addc` works as expected:

```
printfn "%A" (addc true [true;true;false] [false;false;false])
```

Have a look as this [SO post - F# function calling syntax confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725202/f-function-calling-syntax-confusion) - it explains functions, function calling and tuples in F#.

Comment: Glad that the answer helped

Comment: @ksw9722 in complement of the answer you may have problem if `l1` happens to be an empty list and not `l2` (as you will end in the `then` part doing `l1.Head` or `l1.Tail` which will provoke an error)

Answer (score 2):

Your functions 'carry' and 'sum' do not take tuples, so 'addc' can be rewritten to

```
let carry a b c = if a then b||c else b&&c
let sum   a b c = if c then a=b else not (a=b)
let rec addc cin (l1:bool list) (l2:bool list) =
    if l2.Length>0 
    then sum cin l1.Head l2.Head :: addc (carry cin l1.Head l2.Head) l1.Tail l2.Tail 
    else l1
```

Compiles to

```
val carry : a:bool -> b:bool -> c:bool -> bool
val sum : a:'a -> b:'a -> c:bool -> bool when 'a : equality
val addc : cin:bool -> l1:bool list -> l2:bool list -> bool list
```