# .fsx script ignoring a function call when I add a parameter to it

Tags: f#, fsi, f#-scripting

Alright, so I'm a happy fsx-script programmer, because I love how I can have the compiler shout at me when I do mistakes before they show up at runtime.

However I've found a case which really bothers me because I was expecting that by doing some refactoring (i.e.: adding an argument to a function) I was going to be warned by the compiler about all the places where I need to put the new argument. But, not only this did **not** happen, fsharpi ran my script and **ignored the function call completely!!** :(

How can I expect to refactor my scripts if this happens?

Here is my code:

```
let Foo (bar: string) =
    Console.WriteLine("I received " + bar)

Foo("hey")
```

It works.

Now, later, I decide to add a second argument to the function (but I forget to add the argument to all the calls to it):

```
let Foo (bar: string) (baz: bool) =
    Console.WriteLine("I received " + bar)

Foo("hey")
```

The result of this is: instead of the compiler telling me that I'm missing an argument, it is `fsharpi` running the script and ignoring the call to `Foo`! Why?

PS: I know the difference between currying and tuples, so I know `Foo("hey")` becomes a function (instead of a function call), because of **partial application**. But I want to understand better why the compiler is not expecting a function evaluation here, instead of seeing a function and ignoring it. Can I enable a warningAsError somehow? I would like to avoid resorting to using tuples in order to workaround this problem.

Comment: Bound to be a duplicate, but you have discovered currying - `Foo("hey")` is a function

Comment: The answer here answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725202/f-function-calling-syntax-confusion?rq=1.  Also, you were almost certainly warned about some weird return types in various places by the compiler

Comment: I know I'm using currying, but I thought it was the preferred way of using arguments in F# (as opposed to C#-style arguments). And then I know that Foo("hey") is a function, but shouldn't the compiler still throw an error?

Comment: If you were actually using `Foo` you almost certainly got an error/warning - For example `if true then Foo "hey" else ()` won't compile

Comment: I've read the answer linked and it's just explaining currying, which I already knew about. What doesn't explain is why the fsharpi compiler doesn't throw an error when finding a function. Shouldn't it expect to find all arguments to the function if it's not a function declaration but a call to it?

Comment: In your first example, Foo(hey) has sufficient parameters to be fully evaluated, so it executes the writeline and returns unit (like no return type). In the second example, Foo(hey) evaluates to a function that takes a bool only

Comment: but I'm writing a script, if I write Foo() I simply want Foo to be called, I don't need to write an if-else structure for that

Comment: why should it - it is perfectly fine to write a function which returned `Foo "hey"` - in fact that is the whole point of using currying

Comment: I said I completely understand that `Foo "hey"` is a function, yes, but inside an F# script, all lines should be expected to be evaluated as `unit`, except when declaring a function/module/type

Comment: In a .fs file, an expression which doesn't evaluate to unit is only a warning. (IIRC)

Comment: @marklam, that's good to know, is there a way to make `fsharpi` report warnings as errors?

Comment: Can't see anything, sorry.

Comment: Question what do you think `1;;` in fsi should do? How is it different to `foo "hey"`?

Comment: I think fsi should report an error when seeing `1;;`, definitely. @marklam, there's a --warnaserror flag for fsharpi (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/fsharpi.1.html) but even when using it, it's not reporting the warning you mention

Comment: Seriously? the whole point of F# interactive is that it is interactive - if you have a value it prints out what its value is

Comment: I use F# for scripting, not for REPL, do you have a better suggestion for me?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: statically typed scripts that don't break when refactored

Comment: I don't know of any tools for such refactoring F# code. Your question is a little misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The `fsharpi` (or `fsi` if you're on Windows) interpreter makes no distinction between running a script and typing code at the interactive prompt (or, most often, submitting code from your editor via a select-and-hit-Alt-Enter keyboard shortcut).

Therefore, if you got what you're asking for -- `fsharpi` issuing a warning whenever a script line has a return value that isn't `()` -- it would ruin the value of `fsharpi` for the most common use case, which is people using an interactive `fsharpi` session to test their code, and rapidly iterate through non-working prototypes to get to one that works correctly. This is one of F#'s great strengths, and giving you what you're asking for would eliminate that strength. It is therefore **never** going to happen.

**BUT**... that doesn't mean that you're sunk. If you have functions that return `unit`, and you want `fsharpi` to give you a compile-time error when you refactor them to take more arguments, you can do it this way. Replace all occurrences of:

```
Foo("hey")
```

with:

```
() = Foo("hey")
```

As long as the function `Foo` has only one argument (and returns null), this will evaluate to `true`; the `true` value will be happily ignored by `fsharpi`, and your script will run. However, if you then change `Foo` to take two arguments, so that `Foo("hey")` now returns a function, the `() = Foo("hey")` line will no longer compile, and you'll get an error like:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    unit
but here has type
    'a -> unit
```

So if you want `fsharpi` to refuse to compile your script when you refactor a function, go through and change your calls to `() = myfunc arg1 arg2`. For functions that don't return `unit`, make the value you're testing against a value of that function's return type. For example, given this function:

```
let f x = x * 2
```

You could do

```
0 = f 5
```

This will be `false`, of course, but it will compile. But if you refactor `f`:

```
let f x y = x * 2 + y
```

Now the line `0 = f 5` will not compile, but will give you the error message:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int
but here has type
    int -> int
```

To summarize: you won't ever get the feature you're looking for, because it would harm the language. But with a bit of work, you can do something that fits your needs.

Or in other words, as the famous philosopher Mick Jagger once put it:

> You can't always get what you want. But if you try, sometimes you might find you get what you need.

Comment: thanks so much for providing a helpful answer instead of the conservative and dismissive style comments I was getting in the question; I will try this and report back (and mark as accepted accordingly); btw, do you think contributing a "flag" to `fsi` to make it work in a non-interactive way, that is, reporting an error for expressions that resolve to a value instead of `unit`, would be accepted?