# Parenthesis change the function signature

Tags: f#

When I set parenthesis in a function definition, the function types change.

I have two functions: [addition1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBuqp.png)(without parenthesis) and [addition2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKeYj.png) (with parenthesis). The types are the same, but the function signature is different. Why is the type different?

```
let addition1 a b =
  a + b
//val addition1 : a:int -> b:int -> int

let addition2(a, b) = 
  a + b
//val addition2 : a:int * b:int -> int
```

Comment: You also added a comma which is the big change

Comment: It's not the same, first function is taking two parameters (actually taking first parameter  then creating a function taking the second parameter). And can be curried. Second function is taking one parameter, that is a tuple. First form is common for F# code, second one is more for interop with BCL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# function calling syntax confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725202/f-function-calling-syntax-confusion)

Comment: @s952163 I understand. Is there some significant difference?

Comment: Please see this: [A Common Mistake: Tuple vs Multiple Parameters](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/defining-functions/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The types are the same, but the function signature is different. Why the type different?

The types aren't actually the same.

When you write:

```
let addition1 a b = a + b
```

You create a function which is distinctly different than

```
let addition2 (a, b) = a + b
```

In the second case, the parenthesis and comma are creating a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/tuples), meaning that your function accepts a single parameter, which is a tuple (typed as `int * int`), and returns an `int`.

The first case creates a function which can be curried.  The type signature of `int -> int -> int` means that it creates a function which accepts an int, and then *returns a function which accepts and int and returns an int*.  This allows you to use partial application:

```
let partially_applied_addition1 = addition1 3
```

For details, see [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/functions/) in the official docs, and [Currying from fsharpforfunandprofit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/).

Allowing for currying is much more common in F# code.  In general, using tuples as a parameter is mostly done for interop scenarios with the base class libraries or when planning an API to be used from C# or other languages.  Being able to partially apply allows things like piping to work properly:

```
let answer =
    getSomeIntegerValue ()
    |> addition1 12 // Add 12 to result
```

The tupled form will not compile with the above, as it cannot work with partial application.